# Improve spider drawing in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is the spider I have drawn in Tikz (for a scientific paper using a spider as a stimulus!):

[image: spider]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [fill=black] (0,0) ellipse (1.5cm and .8cm);
\draw (0,0) parabola (3,-3);
\draw (0,0) parabola (3,-2);
\draw (0,0) parabola (3,-1);
\draw (0,0) parabola (3,-.5);
\draw (0,0) parabola (-3,-3);
\draw (0,0) parabola (-3,-2);
\draw (0,0) parabola (-3,-1);
\draw (0,0) parabola (-3,-.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone improve over my attempt?

UPDATE:
I'm leaning towards something more like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle(.5cm);
\draw [fill=black] (0,1) circle(.8cm);
\draw[thick] (0,.1) parabola (2,3);
\draw[thick] (0,.05) parabola (2,1);
\draw[thick] (0,0) parabola (2,-1);
\draw[thick] (0,0) parabola (2,-3);
\draw[thick] (0,-.3) parabola (.3,-.8);

\draw[thick] (0,.1) parabola (-2,3);
\draw[thick] (0,.05) parabola (-2,1);
\draw[thick] (0,0) parabola (-2,-1);
\draw[thick] (0,0) parabola (-2,-3);
\draw[thick] (0,-.3) parabola (-.3,-.8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to let people here know what you mean by "improve". What do you specifically want to improve?

Comment: I was hoping to stimulate a variety of answers (clever, funny etc) of different ways of producing a spider like graphic in Tikz (or other Tex based code), and in the process learn a little bit more (and use the most appropriate in my paper). Obviously it hasn't gone down too well, but I'm actually happy with my second attempt.

Answer (score 8):

`;^b`  EDITED to clean up code, add blood!

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\fang{\stackon[-7pt]{\raisebox{-2.5pt}{V}}{\textcolor{red}{v}}}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\spider
\savebox\spider{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [fill=black] (0,0) ellipse (1.5cm and .8cm);
\draw (0,0) parabola (3,-3);
\draw (0,0) parabola (3,-2);
\draw (0,0) parabola (3,-1);
\draw (0,0) parabola (3,-.5);
\draw (0,0) parabola (-3,-3);
\draw (0,0) parabola (-3,-2);
\draw (0,0) parabola (-3,-1);
\draw (0,0) parabola (-3,-.5);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
{\sffamily\color{white}
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{.65cm}{\makebox[0pt]{v\fang vv\fang v}}{%
  \stackinset{c}{-.3cm}{c}{1.2cm}{O}{%
    \stackinset{c}{+.3cm}{c}{1.2cm}{O}{%
      \usebox{\spider}%
}}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ha. Very good. Not quite appropriate for a scientific paper though! :) This is a good halloween spider...

Comment: @Frank_Zafka If you are looking for something more "authentic", then a simple google image search of "spider silhouette" will provide you with untold numbers of graphics that can be inserted with `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Obviously I could include a spider picture but was interested in any adaptations to my code that I hadn't already thought of. :)